# Как обосновать постановку всех запятых в этом фрагменте романа Л.Толстого?

Tags: пунктуация

Князь Василий исполнил обещание, данное на вечере у Анны Павловны княгине Друбецкой, просившей его о своем единственном сыне Борисе. О нем было доложена государю, и, не в пример другим, он был переведен в гвардии Семеновский полк прапорщиком. Но адъютантом или состоящим при Кутузове Борис так и не был назначен, несмотря на все хлопоты и происки Анны Михайловны.
Вскоре после вечера Анны Павловны Анна Михайловна вернулась в Москву, прямо к своим богатым родственникам Ростовым, у которых она стояла в Москве и у которых с детства воспитывался и годами живал её обожаемый Боренька, только что произведенный в армейские и тотчас переведенный в гвардейские прапорщики. Гвардия уже вышла из Петербурга 10-го августа, и сын, оставшийся для обмундирования в Москве, должен был догнать ее по дороге в Радзивилов.
У Ростовых были именинницы Натальи — мать и меньшая дочь. С утра не переставая подъезжали и отъезжали цуги, подвозившие поздравителей к большому, всей Москве известному дому графини Ростовой на Поварской.Молодежь была в задних комнатах, не находя нужным участвовать в приеме визитов. Граф встречал и провожал гостей, приглашая всех к обеду.

Comment: Пожалуйста, пронумеруйте все запятые и выскажите свою версию обоснования для каждой запятой. Участники форума проверят ваше решение.

Answer (score 1):

Князь Василий исполнил обещание, (1) данное на вечере у Анны Павловны княгине Друбецкой,(2) просившей его о своем единственном сыне Борисе.

1,2 - запятая обособляет определительные обороты. Правило:

Обособляются (отделяются запятой, а в середине предложения выделяются с двух сторон запятыми) распространенные определения, выраженные причастием или прилагательным с зависящими от него словами (так называемые определительные обороты), стоящие после существительного или субстантивированного слова.

О нем было доложено государю,(3) и,(4) не в пример другим,(5) он был переведен в гвардии Семеновский полк прапорщиком.

3 - запятая между частями сложносочиненного предложения. Первая часть - *О нем было доложено государю*, вторая *не в пример другим, он был переведен в гвардии Семеновский полк прапорщиком*

Правило:

1. Запятыми разделяются части сложносочиненного предложения, между которыми стоит соединительный союз *и*.

4,5 - запятые при обособленном обороте, выраженном наречием с зависимым словом.

Правило:

Для смыслового подчеркивания могут обособляться некоторые обстоятельства, выраженные наречиями (с зависимыми словами или без них).

Но адъютантом или состоящим при Кутузове Борис так и не был назначен,(6) несмотря на все хлопоты и происки Анны Михайловны.

6 - запятая при обособленном обороте, выраженном существительным с предлогом *несмотря на*.

Правило:

Для смыслового выделения или попутного пояснения могут выделяться
обстоятельства, выраженные именами существительными в косвенных падежах
(обычно с предлогами), особенно если при этих существительных имеются
пояснительные слова.

Чаще всего такие конструкции образуются именами существительными с предлогами или предложными сочетаниями ввиду, вследствие, благодаря, по причине, наподобие, подобно, при условии, при наличии, при, вопреки, НЕСМОТРЯ НА, за неимением, согласно, с согласия, во избежание и др.,

Вскоре после вечера Анны Павловны Анна Михайловна вернулась в Москву,(7) прямо к своим богатым родственникам Ростовым,(8) у которых она стояла в Москве (8') и у которых с детства воспитывался и годами живал её обожаемый Боренька,(9) только что произведенный в армейские и тотчас переведенный в гвардейские прапорщики.

7 - обстоятельство, выраженное именем существительным в косвенном падеже с предлогом.

8 - запятая между главным и придаточным предложением.

Правило:

Придаточное предложение отделяется от главного запятой или выделяется запятыми с двух сторон, если находится внутри главного предложения.

8' - Между однородными придаточными предложениями, соединенными неповторяющимся соединительным или разделительным союзом, запятая не ставится.

9 - распространенное  определение, выраженное причастиями, стоящими после определяемого существительного - *Боренька*.

Гвардия уже вышла из Петербурга 10-го августа,(10) и сын, (11) оставшийся для обмундирования в Москве,(12) должен был догнать ее по дороге в Радзивилов.

10 - запятая между частями сложносочиненного предложения.

11,12- обособляют определительный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова.

У Ростовых были именинницы Натальи — (13) мать и меньшая дочь.

13 - тире отделяет приложение.

Правило:

Вместо запятой при обособлении приложений употребляется тире:
а)      если перед приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова «а именно».

С утра не переставая подъезжали и отъезжали цуги,(14) подвозившие поздравителей к большому,(15) всей Москве известному дому графини Ростовой на Поварской.

14 - определительный оборот.

15 - однородные определения.(?????)

Молодежь была в задних комнатах,(16) не находя нужным участвовать в приеме визитов. Граф встречал и провожал гостей,(17) приглашая всех к обеду.

16,17 - запятые отделяют обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастными оборотами.

Правило:

Деепричастный оборот, как правило, обособляется независимо от места, занимаемого им по отношению к глаголу-сказуемому.